# Positronium splitting?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, antimatter

To my understanding, positronium has an average lifespan of around 140 ns before decaying, but can the positronium atom be “split” into its constituent particles, say with a strong magnetic field, before annihilating?

Comment: Why the downvote?  A sufficiently energetic photon should do the trick (theoretically), but whether an experiment is possible or not is another matter.

Answer (score 5):

The lifetime of positronium depends on whether it is in the singlet or triplet state (para- or ortho-positronium). The former has a lifetime of about 125 ps, the latter, as you stated, around 142 ns. [source: wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium)

The binding energy can be calculated to be about 6.8 eV - so a well-aimed photon should be able to split positronium. Experiments to measure hyperfine splitting [have been reported](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6923) - this suggests that the EM interactions of positronium behave as expected.